# Inject a Stage Variable into my API Gateway body-mapping-template

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, velocity, aws-step-functions

I'm using API Gateway to direct requests to a Step Function (State Machine).

I'm following the steps here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-api-gateway.html

I have a step in my state machine where I check for the value of a given variable that is in my input payload. If the 'stage' variable is equal to 'prod' it invokes the prod lambda otherwise it invokes the testing one, simple enough.

Ideally I'd like to inject a Stage Variable in my API Gateway inside my body-mapping template. Following what is explained here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-api-gateway.html#api-gateway-step-3) I have the following template :

```json
{
    "input": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$'))",
    "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123456789012:stateMachine:nameOfMyStateMachine"
}
```

For this to work it would be great if my stage variable would be injected inside the `input` object.

So I would have

```json
# before I inject the Stage Variable
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
}
```

```json
# after I inject the Stage Variable
{
    "stage": "prod",
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
}
```

Given the templating language, I'm guessing the easy way would be to pass the variable outside of the "input" object so I would end up with

```json
{
    "stage": "prod",
    "input": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$'))",
    "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123456789012:stateMachine:nameOfMyStateMachine"
}
```

but that won't help as only the payload inside "body" gets passed to the step function (and I would like it to stay that way)

My question is, is there a way to manipulate/append the content of "input" inside the body-template snippet ?

Something like

```js
const stage = $.stageVariables.stage;
# some code that append stage to the input.json() ?
{
    "input": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$'))",
    "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123456789012:stateMachine:nameOfMyStateMachine"
}
```

hope that makes sense

EDIT

After looking around, I thought I had it with the following but nope :

```java
#set($inputJson = $util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$')))
$util.qr($inputJson.put("stage", ${stageVariables.stage}))
{
    "input": "$inputJson",
    "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123456789012:stateMachine:nameOfMyStateMachine"
}
```

:(